# Meteor: How do I count Tweets per Minute, rather than all Tweets scraped?

Tags: javascript, meteor, twitter

I'm using Meteor to use Twitters API to scrap Tweets with a certain hashtag. At the moment I'm using my surname, Cusack, see the live demo: https://tweetmonitor.io.

I can only get the total amount of Tweets since I started scraping, but I want to store the count on a minute-by-minute basis. I could then calculate averages, etc.

Does anyone have any idea? Here's my code so far:

```
Meteor.subscribe("tweets");

Template.tweetsList.helpers({
// We need to make sure the count is of the current minute
tweetscount: function() 
{
    // Let's count the tweets
    function tweetCount()
    {
        return Tweets.find().count();
    }

    return tweetCount();
}
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Need more info. Define "tweets per minute." Tweets per minute over the lifetime of the account? The past 24 hours? The past hour? Tweets per minute = # of tweets / # of minutes in tracked time period. Only count tweets that were made within that time period. If you don't actually know how to do any of that in Meteor, ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad, so this answer is very broad.

1. Get tweets.
2. Sort tweets by timestamp.
3. Choose a time period over which you want to track tweets per minute. Is this tweets per minute (TPM) over the lifetime of the account? Over the past hour? The past minute?
4. Break tweets into chunks corresponding to your time period based on their timestamp.
5. Count the number of tweets in each chunk and divide the count by the number of minutes in the chunk.